# resolving invalid cursor state in a for loop

Tags: java, ms-access, for-loop, pivot, sqlexception

I have a method which retrieve its values from a database. The query that I'm passing worked fine when i tried it in ms access. the error occurs in "results[rowCount][i] = rs.getString(i+1);" this is my full code for the method.

```
private String[][] connectToDB2(String query) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        String[][] results = null;
        try {

                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                String db = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:/EACA_AgroVentures1.accdb";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();

                int columns = rsm.getColumnCount();
                int rows = getRowCount(rs);
                if(query.contains("PIVOT") ){
                    System.out.println(query);
                    rows=getRowCount2(query);

                }else if(query.contains("GROUP BY")){
                    rows = getRowCount(query);
                }
                //int rows = rs.getFetchSize();
                int rowCount = 0;
                results = new String[rows][columns];
                System.out.println(rows+" PIVOT "+columns);


                System.out.println("Entering While Loop");
                do{    
                   System.out.println(rowCount);
                   if(rowCount == rows){
                        return results;
                   }else{
                        for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
                            System.out.println("Running While Loop");
                            rs.next();
                            results[rowCount][i] = rs.getString(i+1);
                            System.out.println(rowCount+",,,,"+i+" = "+results[rowCount][i]);
                        }
                     rowCount++;
                   }
                }while(rs.isAfterLast()==true);
                System.out.println("Exiting While Loop");
                rs.getStatement().close();
                conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }
```

thank you in advance.

EDIT: I've changed the ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE into ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY then changed the do-while into a while. All results already show but with an arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. How can I resolve this? Below is my updated code.

```
private String[][] connectToDB2(String query) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        String[][] results = null;
        try {

                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                String db = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:/EACA_AgroVentures1.accdb";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();

                int columns = rsm.getColumnCount();
                int rows = getRowCount(rs);
                if(query.contains("PIVOT") ){
                    System.out.println(query);
                    rows=getRowCount2(query);

                }else if(query.contains("GROUP BY")){
                    rows = getRowCount(query);
                }
                //int rows = rs.getFetchSize();
                int rowCount = 0;
                results = new String[rows][columns];
                System.out.println(rows+" PIVOT "+columns);

                System.out.println("Entering While Loop");
                while (rs.next()) { 
                    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
                        System.out.println("Running While Loop");
                        results[rowCount][i] = rs.getString(i+1);
                        System.out.println(rowCount+",,,,"+i+" = "+results[rowCount][i]);
                     }
                     rowCount++;
                }

                System.out.println("Exiting While Loop");
                rs.getStatement().close();
                conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }
```

this is the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 41
    at com.eaca.MainFrame.connectToDB2(MainFrame.java:224)
    at com.eaca.MainFrame.attendanceView(MainFrame.java:469)
    at com.eaca.MainFrame.access$600(MainFrame.java:53)
    at com.eaca.MainFrame$ChangeTab.stateChanged(MainFrame.java:536)
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.fireStateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:416)
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane$ModelListener.stateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:270)
    at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:132)
    at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:67)
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndexImpl(JTabbedPane.java:616)
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(JTabbedPane.java:591)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3644)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6502)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
27,,,,0 = 23    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `ResultSet.next()` multiple times for each iteration of the rows - once per column, inside the `for` loop - this ultimately results in the exception, as you try to move way past the end of it. On a more general nore, this is quite an awkward way to iterate a `ResultSet`. Using the conventional `while` loop should make your life easier:

```
int rowCount = 0;
while (rs.next()) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
        System.out.println("Running While Loop");
        results[rowCount][i] = rs.getString(i+1);
        System.out.println(rowCount+",,,,"+i+" = "+results[rowCount][i]);
     }
     rowCount++;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it says that it cannot find symbol hasNext(). What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: @user3615601 that was a dumb mistake in my part. Fixed.

Comment: is there any other approach I can do for this?

Answer (score 1):

When the Access Database Engine processes any query with a `GROUP BY` clause (including crosstab queries) it returns a recordset that is not updateable. Therefore you cannot use `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` or `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` as the `resultSetType`; you must use `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` (which is the default).

Comment: I changed TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE into TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY as suggested, the invalid cursor state error was removed but now, it returns a "java.sql.SQLException: Result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY".